# How to fix Excel COM error cause by Python xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, windows, com, xlwings

The first time I use xlwing, I can get result successfully.

But when choose different `.xlsx` file, I get error.

I have try to shut down `EXCEL.EXE` in `taskman`, but not work still.

#### Code

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import xlwings as xw
import time

excel_path = "file.xlsx"
sheet_name = "sheet1"
img_path = "test.png"

app = xw.App(visible=False, add_book=False)

wb = app.books.open(excel_path)
sheet = wb.sheets(sheet_name)

all = sheet.used_range
all.api.CopyPicture()

sheet.api.Paste()

pic = sheet.pictures[-1]
pic.api.Copy()

time.sleep(3)

img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img.save(img_path)

pic.delete()
wb.save(excel_path)
wb.close()
app.quit()
```

#### Result

`com_error: (-2147417851, 'The server threw an exception。', None, None)`

- I think this is because i **didn't release the com object.** (I should use `app.kill()` instead of `app.quit()`)
- But now, I cannot solve this problem, I have try to shut down and restart computer...
- Hope someone can help me or tell me how to fix.
- Besides, I convert to use first time `.xlsx` file work withour any error, but other file not work.

Comment: -2147417851 is RPC_E_SERVERFAULT, it tells us nothing, it just means the COM "server", here maybe Excel (you don't say which line) crashed or reported a generic problem. It's certainly not because you didn't release something.

Comment: @SimonMourier, 
Actually I used different computers to test:

(1) Using `app.kill()` in endline, it will be fine everything.

(2) Then I using `app.quit()` second time, the `com_error` occur. 

Therefore, that's what I think problem is from I didn't release something.